# Can't get any unit tests to run in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm trying to write a simple unit test. This test function will call my service, which grabs info from the database, pushes it to a list and returns it. I've looked high and low in the debug logs to find what could be causing, but it seems nothing on the web is helping me out. I'm not too familiar with Spring Boot, but it seems surprising that all this effort and I am unable to get a simple unit test to pass.

## Error Logs

http://text-share.com/view/fb0369c3

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
```

## Example Test

```
package com.algoq.algoq;

import com.algoq.algoq.models.Subscriber;
import com.algoq.algoq.respositories.SubscriberRepository;
import com.algoq.algoq.services.AlgorithmService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        AlgoQApplication.class,
        })
public class ExampleTest extends AlgoQApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private AlgorithmService aService;

    @MockBean
    private SubscriberRepository employeeRepository;

    @Bean
    public AlgorithmService aService() {
        return new AlgorithmService();
    }


    @Test
    public void subscriberListNull() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Subscriber> subs = aService.getSubscribers();
        assertThat(subs).isEmpty();
    }

}
```

## Service

```
package com.algoq.algoq.services;

import com.algoq.algoq.models.Subscriber;
import com.algoq.algoq.respositories.SubscriberRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class AlgorithmService {

    @Autowired
    private SubscriberRepository subRep;

    /**
     * Gets a list of subscribers to return to the API
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<Subscriber> getSubscribers() {
        ArrayList<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<>();
        subRep.findAll()
                .forEach(subscribers::add);
        return subscribers;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new subscriber to the database
     * @param sub
     * @return
     */
    public void addSubscriber(Subscriber sub) {
        subRep.save(sub);
    }

    /**
     * Finds a single user id
     * @param email
     * @return
     */
    public List<Subscriber> getSubscriber(String email) {
        return subRep.findByEmailAddress(email);
    }
}
```

## Application

```
package com.algoq.algoq;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableScheduling
public class AlgoQApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AlgoQApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

## POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.algoQ</groupId>
    <artifactId>algo-q</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>algo-q</name>
    <description>An algorithm a day keeps the brain up to date</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.python</groupId>
            <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.4.194</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pygments</groupId>
            <artifactId>pygments</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real cause of the exception is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

So I believe you need to add JAXBE library to your classpath (it was removed from JDK in java9 and I guess you are using java9)

Try to add this to your pom file

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I feel like this is getting super close.. I'm still getting an error, but it looks a lot better. I'm thinking this is a JPA error?
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.algoq.algoq.services.AlgorithmService.getSubscribers(AlgorithmService.java:26)
 at com.algoq.algoq.ExampleTest.subscriberListNull(ExampleTest.java:42)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: I suppose some issues with @MockBean. I guess it is returning null, you need to setup it first, see example here https://dzone.com/articles/mockbean-spring-boots-missing-ingredient
i.e.   when(employeeRepository.findAll()) .thenReturn(new ArrayList());

Answer (score 1):

**JDK**

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

**pom.xml**

> 1.8

Are you using java 8 or 9 ?

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Issue with **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException** ,

Run the application with Java 8 environement or Include the JAXB library for Java 9, JAXB API are not included in JAVA SE 9. Refer [Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a future version.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html). Use --add-modules ( *--add-modules java.xml.bind* ) to add module in classpath. Jave has only deprecated and does not add javax.xml.bind module on classpath by default.

Otherwise include as dependency through maven.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```